# Finding density and distribution of $X=\tan(\theta)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

Here is a problem I'm trying to solve and wanted to check if my solution was ok.

A searchlight is distance 1 from a wall. Let $Q$ denote the point on the wall
directly opposite it and assume it scans along the wall so that at any given
time, the angle, $\theta$, the beam of light makes with the perpendicular from the
light to $Q$ is uniform on $(−\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Let $X\in \mathbb R$ be the position of the beam
on the wall as measured from $Q$. Find the distribution and density functions
for $X$.

**My attempt:**
Drawing the picture, I believe $X=\tan(\theta)$ for $\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.The density of $\theta$, $f_{\theta}$, is $\frac{1}{\pi}$ on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, $0$ everywhere else.

Taking $F_X,F_{\theta}$ to be the distribution functions of $X,\theta$:
\begin{align}
F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)& =P(\tan(\theta)\leq x)\\
& =P(\theta \leq \arctan(x))\\
& =F_{\theta}(\arctan(x))\\
& =\int 1_{(-\infty, \arctan(x)]}\frac{1}{\pi} dy\\
& =\int_{-\pi/2}^{\arctan(x)}\frac{1}{\pi}dy\\
& =\frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Now taking the derivative of the distribution,
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi+\pi x^2}$$

Therefore we have $F_X(x)=\frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}$, density $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\pi+\pi x^2}$. It would be great if I could get this proof/calculation checked, and be corrected if/where I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: looks good to me, you ended up with the Cauchy distribution, I believe

Comment: @gt6989b Is my interpretation of the "word' problem is fine, I'm guessing then?

Comment: i'd have modeled the same way

Comment: @gt6989b I tried to take a Lebesgue integral approach to solve it, but ended up using the equality between Riemann and Lebesgue integral and just solved the Riemann integral instead. Is that ok to do? When is it not ok to do that?

Comment: Sometimes (not here), a function may be Lebesgue-integrable but not Riemann-integrable. For example, $f(x) = \mathbb{I}_{x \in \mathbb{Q}}$ comes to mind...

Comment: Yes, if $\theta$ is uniform on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, then $\tan \theta$ is indeed standard Cauchy.